# remove trailing blanks

Tags: c, if-statement, whitespace

I'm working through k&r and I'm working on problem 1-18. Write a program to remove TRAILING blanks and tabs from each line of input and to delete entirely blank lines. My idea is to read in each line and have a count for the number of spaces. If it is the first blank print it using putchar. If there is a second blank do not print it and reset spaces to 0. Then continue to read through and remove spaces.

At the moment I have it to just print anything else it reads because I am attempting to do it bit by bit. Once I run this program I get two of these �� in the terminal. I think I am having problems nesting the if statement or the else statement incorrectly, I had some errors on there earlier. Am I going about the logic of removing blanks the correct way? If someone could point me in the right direction to fix the code I would be grateful.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c, i, spaces;             /*c for input, i for counting*/

    i = 0;
    c = 0;
    spaces = 0;
    while ((c = getchar())!=EOF)
            if(spaces = 0 && c == ' ')
                    ++spaces;
                    putchar(c);
                    if(spaces >= 1)
                            spaces = 0;
            else {
                    putchar(c);
            }


}
```

Comment: I didn't check the rest of the logic, but this `if(spaces = 0 && c == ' ')` should probably be `if(spaces == 0 && c == ' ')`.  `=` vs. `==`

Comment: thanks, silly mistake. that decreases the weird question mark in the terminal to one

Comment: Are you supposed to use getchar() to solve this (instead of reading a whole line)?

Comment: I've only seen getchar() so far in the book

Comment: You say you want to remove TRAILING spaces. I don't think it is possible to know if a space is trailing until you have read the whole line. Unless the line will never have embedded spaces, in which case you would need a flag for non-spaces, not spaces.

Comment: I was thinking of using something like INSPACE and OUTSPACE, I will try and write it using those methods

Comment: Also note that `if(spaces = 0 && c == ' ')` isn't followed by an opening brace, so `putchar (c)` isn't covered by it, and is therefore not protected by the `if`, _and_ it's outside the `while`. See Luchian Grigore's answer. You should _always_ put braces round while and if bodies, even for single statements when it's formally redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
if(spaces == 0 && c == ' ')
{
   ++spaces;
   putchar(c);
   if(spaces >= 1)
      spaces = 0;
}
else 
{
   putchar(c);
}
```

your indentation suggests you want the `else` branch to go with the first if, but as it is now, it corresponds with the inner `if`.

Also, `spaces = 0` is an assignment, `spaces == 0` is a comparison.

Comment: the program atleast runs now thank you, it does not however do what it is supposed to do. Perhaps I am doing it the wrong way

Comment: It basically puts all the characters back out correctly and runs fine. It does not remove trailing blank spaces though

Comment: Well then I don't understand your question

Comment: @bigl do you know what debugging means?

Comment: Fix bugs and errors? Perhaps we think about things differently.

Comment: I see thanks. I've never used this before as I am quite new. I've rewrote it to work now

Answer (score 0):

- Read a string.
- Find the end of the string using strlen() or similar method.
- `for(i=string_length-i; i>=0; i--)`  or use pointers if you prefer.
- Break loop upon first non-space found.
- Insert a null termination at first non-space+1.